# Tree's branch ends to the same leaf twice?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, cart, pruning

I am in `R` using the `DoctorVisits` dataset from the `AER` package. I chose the column `lchronic` to make this tree [image]

Thing is that I don't understand why the algorithm made the branch `freerepat: no` seeing as it results in two leaves which are both `no`. The tree is basically equivalent to this pruned one:[image]

Comment: Maybe you could ask the package authors?

Comment: For rare events, one might expect *every* leaf of a tree to be a no. Some “no”’s may just be more likely than others.

Answer (score 1):

Decision trees (generally) choose splits to minimize impurity within the nodes.  If a split can change a 75% "no" node into two children with 99% no and 51% no (respectively), then it is reasonably likely to do so, even if the final predicted (majority) class in both children is "no".